# Giveaway Command nextcord

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

my discord bot needs a giveaway command. it is correctly sending the giveaway message, but for some reason, it isn't capable to determine the winner. this is the command:

```py
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def giveaway(self, ctx, time, winners: int, prize):
        channel = ctx.channel
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Giveaway!",description=f"{prize}",color=nextcord.Color.green())
        embed.add_field(name="Giveaway de:", value=ctx.author.mention)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Fini dans {time}!")
        msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("")
        d = time[-1]
        num = int(time[:-1])
        if d == "s":
            await asyncio.sleep(num)
        elif d == "m":
            await asyncio.sleep(num * 60)
        elif d == "h":
            await asyncio.sleep(num * 60 * 60)
        elif d == "d":
            await asyncio.sleep(num * 60 * 60 * 24)
        winners_number = winners[:-1]
        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
        users_mention = []
        for i in range(winners_number):
            users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
            users.pop(users.index(self.bot.user))
            winner = random.choice(users)
            users_mention.append(winner.mention)
            users.remove(winner)
            await ctx.send(f"Congratulations {users_mention} you won the giveaway !")
```

error:
[image]

Comment: Is your question what "int" means?

Comment: `winners` is defined as an `int`, what exactly are you trying to do when you run `winners[:-1]` like you're expecting it to be a list or list-like object?

Comment: no. i know what is an integrer. I just want someone to explain me the error and tell me a solution

Comment: The error is that you have an integer and treat it as if it were a list. The solution is to pass an actual list as `winners`, or to not try to use it as one.

Comment: i know that its working, but when a winner is chosen, it sends a list